# Unable to connect to AWS Elasticsearch from local computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I just created a production server on AWS ES with the default settings but I am unable to connect to it from my local computer.

On postman, the request times out always.

I am not sure what details I should be sharing in order to solve this issue, so please ask me and I will share the required details to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have never created one before, but just dry running the "AWS ES - Getting Started",
it does ask for ES Domain to be created in a VPC, and a Subnet, and is subject to a "Security Group" - else you enable the "public access"[image]

Should you not have "public access" enabled, just check if "security group" is proper:

`nc -v <esdomain> 9200` # using netcat e.g https://linuxconfig.org/install-netcat-on-redhat-8 for Centos Machine
if it results in succeeded! you can connect, however curl -XGET :9200/_cat/indices?v could be some other issue.
If not, make sure the "Inbound Rules" in you security group, have your IP allowed:

edit inbound rules of the "Security Group" you have attached to the AWS ES Domain.

[image]

The above, is just a preliminary, and not complete level of debugging. Should this not work, other network aspects need to be explored (i.e VPC, Subnet, ES Domain)

Comment: my inbound rules allow all ports and all ips. What else can I modify?

Comment: does nc -v <es-domain(or IP) 9200 work? or a curl -XGET <es-ip>/9200/_cat/health?v ?

Comment: chances could be, that you spun up in a private VPC / Subnet, that internet access might not be allowed to, and you may need a nat gateway routed through a public subnet. but first lets check if you are at all, able to connect to the es-ip or not.

Comment: so I had an ec2 instance, and when I ssh into it and try to do `curl -XGET <es-url>` I can access the ES instance perfectly.
The nc command times out from my local ubuntu machine.

Comment: nc command times out, inside that ec2, or on your local system? 
and I hope your es is exposed on 9200? I'm not sure how, AWS ES i.e what port it exposes to, if it is http/https then nc -v <es-url> 80, or 443 may work respectively.

Comment: on my local system. The EC2 is able to access things perfectly. I'm not sure on what port my EC is exposed , but I tried all the common ones. 

Getting an error like(on my local system): nc: getaddrinfo for host "<es-domain>" port 443: Name or service not known

Comment: can you paste your curl -XGET <esurl> command too?
can you paste the sec group inbound rules also?
inside that EC2, just do python3 -m http.server 8181, and attach the same security group to that EC2 which apparentyl allows all ip all port.
can you from local ubuntu do : nc -v es_public_ip 8181?
Most likely some problems with sec grp I suspect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220793/discussion-between-karan-singh-and-khanna).